# Is there a way to break down long texts for comparison?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash

I keep uploading texts (daily) that are about 30 pages long on average (~100'000 characters). Since I need to match the text with future texts, but don't want to load the whole content of the document into a database (which would also be too big), I tried to break it down to a 256 character string.

The goal is to match the text with the match future texts, and output the match in %. To make it easier to check, it would be best for me if I can store a 256-character long string on the DB, and generate future texts also into a 256-character long string, and then compare these strings with each other and return the percentage of match.
(Similar to this [Website](https://60tools.com/en/tool/text-comparison))

Here I read that this doesn't make sense to convert these into hashes, as it takes too much processing power. Are there other possibilities? Or what would make sense for my situation?

Comment: "*don't want to load the whole content of the document into a database (which would also be too big)*" You mean content roughly 0.1MB in size is "*too big*"? How did you reach this conclusion? I routinely work with databases spanning thousands of rows with attributes containing much more information than that.

Comment: Ok, I've been working with rather small databases so far, and thought that there must be a more efficient way than storing several 100'000 characters in a database every day.

Comment: maybe you should consider hashing

Comment: Yes, that sounds like an interesting approach, which I already thought through my head. But how can I calculate the overlap percentage from two hash values?